# Windows get lost moving between workspaces in Expo

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz

[image]

Is there any way to fix this? I'm using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: This looks like a bug with Compiz. Could you please [file a bug report on Launchpad](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) and edit a link to it back into your question if it hasn't already been reported? Thanks!

Comment: WarriororIng64, there is a same report (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/300307) but is kinda 4 years old. Is that okay anyway? (Sorry for my english)

Comment: Yes, that's fine. Hopefully it will get some more attention this time.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/300307) and as such is now closed.